# How can draw this picture in latex Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is my flow chart. I need this picture to draw in Tikz [image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[M/.style={rounded corners,draw=blue!50,on chain,anchor=west},font=\sffamily,node distance=2em and 1.5em]
 \begin{scope}[start chain=R going right,every join/.style={-latex},
    nodes={rounded corners,fill=blue!50,text=white,on chain,join,align=center,minimum width=8em}]
  \node (T1) {Duck};
  \node (T2) {Koala};
  \node (T3) {Buffalo};
  \node (T4) {Squirrel};
  \node (T5) {Anteater};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[start chain=B1 going below,nodes=M]
  \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-2em]T1.east) (B11){Goose};
  \draw ([xshift=1em]T1.south west) |- (B11);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[start chain=B2 going below,nodes=M]
  \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-2em]T2.east) (B21){Hummingbird};
  \node (B22){Camel};
  \foreach \X in {1,2} 
   {\draw ([xshift=1em]T2.south west) |- (B2\X);}
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[start chain=B3 going below,nodes=M]
  \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-2em]T3.east) (B31){Shark};
  \draw ([xshift=1em]T3.south west) |- (B31);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[start chain=B4 going below,nodes={M,text width=6em}]
  \node[anchor=north east] at ([yshift=-2em]T4.east) (B41){Pft pft pft\vspace*{-0.7em}
  \begin{itemize}\itemsep-0.5em\itemindent-1em
   \item Pft
   \item Pft
  \end{itemize}};
  \draw ([xshift=1em]T4.south west) |- (B41);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]